# Execution "df" command on AIX with the bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh, aix

it's very strange that when I am executing df command on AIX with bash like  bash -c "df /" I suppose it will be executed like on Linux, but still the result is same like korn shell. Please give me explanation to this. How can I somehow to be sure that df command output will be same on AIX and on Linux. Before my solution was installing bash on AIX. Now I cannot find any option beside rewrite new script for AIX

Comment: This depends entirely on what version of `df` is installed on each machine; it has nothing to do with which shell you use, and `bash -c "df /"` doesn't really do anything different than `df /` by itself.

Comment: I need universal statement that will  fetch for example used percentage of disk on AIX and Linux. With awk it's not working because of order of the columns. On AIX it's no option to specify fieldlist and their order.

Comment: Requests for code/alternate libraries/documentation/tutorials are off-topic for StackOverflow. You may get some help from http://unix.stackoverflow.com but I believe they work with the same rules regarding on-topic Qs. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer to my question: Output is same on Linux and AIX.
In the following example I want to print /tmp folder disk space information

```
df -Pm | grep -e  'Filesystem' -e '/tmp'
```